# Recursion in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I have a input xml with below structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
<test name="main node">
    <test name="sub node">
        <test name="inner node">sample text</test>
    </test>
</test>
```

And the required output is as below:

```
Group By main node
Group By sub node
Group By inner node
End By inner node
End By sub node
End By main node
```

that is whenever the node 'test' appears, the Group should be started and the end of the group also should be appropriate. For each 'test' node, I need to add a 'Group By @name attribute of  node' and 'End by @name attribute of  node'. Is this possible with recursion?
Can anyone help to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:text>Group By </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="test"/>
    <xsl:text>End By </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces this output when applied to your input:

```
Group By main node
Group By sub node
Group By inner node
End By inner node
End By sub node
End By main node
```

Comment: Thank u so much! Solved my question